# Powershell script does not continue on write-eventlog

Tags: powershell

I have the following block in script that checks a log file and if it finds a specific line, should continue.

```
$keywords=Get-Content "C:\Users\user\desktop\keywords.txt"
Get-Content "C:\Users\user\desktop\some.log" -tail 1 -wait |
ForEach-object {
foreach($word in $keywords) {
if($_ -match "$word") {
Write-EventLog -LogName Application -EventID 2001 -EntryType Information -Source serviceCheck -Message "[SUCCESS] The service has been initialized"
Write-Host "[SUCCESS] The service has been initialized" 
}
}
} | Select -First 1
```

This logs the event but never continues with the rest of the script.
If I put some other command in `if($_ -match "$word") {get-date}` for example or anything else, it works and continues to the next command.

How should this be made to write in event viewer and continue?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon It probably should, it's used to terminate `Get-Content -Wait`

Comment: It works for me.  Every time I append a keyword to the log it runs write-eventlog.

Comment: @js2010 yes, it works, but doesnt continue with the execution.

Comment: That is the logic of your code.  Until get-content stops running, the foreach-object loop will run forever.

Comment: Breaking out of a foreach-object loop is difficult.

Comment: @js2010 the point is - works like charm with anything other than write-eventlog so the question is how to make it work as it is. Give it a try and you will see what it does.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to output *something* for the `Select -First 1` statement to react to:

```
$keywords = Get-Content "C:\Users\user\desktop\keywords.txt"
Get-Content "C:\Users\user\desktop\some.log" -tail 1 -wait |ForEach-object {
    foreach ($word in $keywords) {
        if ($_ -match "$word") {
            Write-EventLog -LogName Application -EventID 2001 -EntryType Information -Source serviceCheck -Message "[SUCCESS] The service has been initialized"
            Write-Host "[SUCCESS] The service has been initialized" 
            "literally any value will do!"
        }
    }
} | Select -First 1 |Out-Null
```

Comment: It doesnt work, I see your point but thats why you have write-host, just to popup something. As I said - with anything different than write-eventlog it works.

Comment: Oh I got it, there is a line  "literally any value will do!" . It does break it and does not print anything. Awesome!

Comment: Oh, so you want to quit the foreach-object loop using "select -first 1", the first time you write an event log.

Comment: @Delyan `Write-Host` doesn't actually output to the pipeline, it writes straight to the host application (hence no effect) :)